# Add values 1- 100 to a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add values 1 - 50 to every element in a 2D array. I created a 5 X 5 array and am trying to populate each cell with a different number(hence 1 - 50). However I can't figure out the what I am doing wrong in the syntax. At the moment and with my current code, I produce 5 rows with the same values repeated:

```
public UF(int N)
{
    count = N;
    id = new int [N][N];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {  int temp = 10;
       temp = temp * counter;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
         id[i][j] = j + temp;
        }
       counter++;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0  11  22  33  33

0  11  22  33  33

0  11  22  33  33

0  11  22  33  33

0  11  22  33  33
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any help

Comment: You're printing the output wrong, apparently.  But you haven't shown us your print code, so we can't tell what might be wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity everyone. I basically just want to initialize the array to look like this:

 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9  10
 11 12 13 14 15

etc. so that each element has a different number

Comment: You already did initialize the array so that each element has a different number.  It looks like 0 1 2 3 4 10 11 12 13 14 20 21 22 23 24 etc.--all different!  If each element having a different number isn't good enough, then please don't repeat the "each element has a different number" requirement, because it's not important.  The key thing, though, is that your output code is not outputting your array.  It's outputting something else.  But you still haven't shown us the output code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question? How would a 5x5 contain every number from 1-50?

Here's an example for a 5x10

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){    
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        table[i][j] = i * 10 + j + 1; // add a one to get from 0-49 to 1-50
    }    
}
```